# Why is Google Chrome loading page and / or resources multiple times?

Tags: javascript, css, image, google-chrome

We have had this problem with one of our web applications for a long time now. Google Chrome loaded all resources twice and ran all scripts and everything on the page twice for some reason.

It could not be because of some refresh or redirect because the developer console did not clear / reset halfway and if there was something refreshing or reloading the page, then that would be happening infinite times.

This only happened on Google Chrome, too. It was making our web application really really slow to load and use.

I am sharing an answer (below?) to this issue at it was surprisingly tough to find cause for and the bug itself lowers performance possibly hundreds of percents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First we thought it was some wacky cache bug, in where the resources somehow got expired during page load, but we could not find anything to support that theory.

Then after some googling I found this: https://codebuildplay.wordpress.com/2014/03/06/chrome-loads-page-twice-sitecore-dms-gets-faulty-usage-data/

They found out that if there are elements with `src = ""` or css-rules like `url('')`, it would cause Google Chrome to think that the src or url refers to the website root path and therefore causes the page with all its resources to be loaded there.

For us this was and was not the case. We had an "extended version" of this same problem by having an `url = "#"`, which seems to be the same as `url = ""`. So having a `#` in the url or src also produces this bug.

The source of this problem can be potentially found by watching the developer console's network view and looking for a cancelled index.php / index.html / similar resource. The line number where this resource was requested should tell where do you have a faulty src attribute. I do not think this works if the problem exists in a css url rule.

I also wrote a small script that might help pinpoint elements that have faulty urls or srcs: https://gist.github.com/ahvonenj/8e2eef80590e200dd297

I hope this helps whoever encounters this really annoying, performance wrecking problem.

Comment: The problem here isn't the browsers, but the incorrect markup.  You shouldn't have had empty `src` attributes anywhere, or ones with just a `#`.  Not sure why you're trying to blame the browser here when it did what it should.

Comment: the cited article is 18 months old, and chrome does not exhibit the behaviour described in the "problem"

Comment: @Archer Only Chrome does this. I don't really see a reason why the default behavior for an empty url or src should be to understand it as the website root path and therefore try and load the whole website there again, causing double or more requests and making all the scripts run multiple times.

Comment: An empty url is equivalent to opening the default document for the current folder.  That is why Chrome *correctly* did this.

Comment: @Archer Does not even matter if Chrome correctly did what it did or not, it still caused a problem. A problem that someone else might encounter as well and thus the question and answer.

Comment: Correct. I'm just making sure you know it did what it should and that it was your error, in case someone else encounters the problem. They need to understand why they did something wrong, in order to avoid it in the future.

Comment: this hint saved me. it was an iframe with src="#" for me

Answer (score 2):

In my case problem solved by linking a valid icon to href below although i have some other empty href / src in my html (its under development yet).
tested on Chrome Android And Desktop Version 56.0

```
<link rel="icon" href="">
```